I am getting the error "index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5" for finding the average heights of an array
I am trying to find the average height of an array containing different heights.  I have to find it using a while loop. Previously I did it with a for loop and it worked but when I try it this way I keep getting the out of bounds error.
I have tried changing the while expression many times but I don't get the result I need or sometimes no result at all.
The code I wrote was :
import numpy as np
N=5
h = np.zeros(N) # heights of family members (in meters)
h[0] = 1.60; h[1] = 1.85; h[2] = 1.75; h[3] = 1.80; h[4] = 0.50

i = 0
sum = 0

while h[i] > 0:
    i = i + 1
    sum = sum + h[i]


average = sum/N
print('Average height: {:g} meters'.format(average))


You can use a condition based on i < N to ensure you don’t go out of bounds and accumulate the sum before incrementing i:
import numpy as np

N = 5
h = np.zeros(N)  # Heights of family members (in meters).
h[0] = 1.60; h[1] = 1.85; h[2] = 1.75; h[3] = 1.80; h[4] = 0.50

i = 0
total_sum = 0  # Changed the variable `sum` to `total_sum` to avoid shadowing the built-in `sum()` function.
while i < N:
    total_sum += h[i]
    i += 1

average = total_sum / N
print(f'Average height: {average:g} meters')

Note, since you are using numpy, consider utilizing the faster vectorized inbuilt function np.mean for this type of thing:
average = np.mean(h)
print(f'Average height: {average:g} meters')

Output for both approaches:
Average height: 1.5 meters

